# How to check for shared space of squares

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I'm trying to make two squares on tkinter's canvas and then check what is their shared space if there is. I wrote this script:

```
from tkinter import *

a1=int(input("enter cord x1: "))
b1=int(input("enter cord y1: "))
n=int(input("enter len 1: "))
a2=int(input("enter cord x2: "))
b2=int(input("enter cord y2: "))
m=int(input("enter len 2: "))

t1=a1+n
g1=b1+n
t2=a2+m
g2=b2+m

master = Tk()

w = Canvas(master, width=2500, height=2000)
w.create_rectangle(a1, b1, t1, g1, fill="blue", outline = 'black')
w.create_rectangle(a2, b2, t2, g2, fill="red", outline = 'black') 
w.pack()

def fun(m,n,a1,b1,a2,b2):
    if a1 < a2 and a1+n > a2:
        if b1 < b2 and b1+n > b2:
            sx=(a1+n-a2)
            sy=(b1+n-b2)
            ts=(sx*sy)
            print ("The shared space is " + str(ts) + " squared pixels!")
        else:
            print ("No Shared Space! please try again")
    else:
        print ("No Shared Space! please try again")

fun(m,n,a1,b1,a2,b2)
master.mainloop()
```

I tested it with a few numbers already, but I couldn't use the tkinter on my computer and I made the calculations in my head. Please tell me if it should work.

Comment: It seems to work for me

Comment: is it paintung the squares correctly?

Comment: Yep, everything looks very good.

Comment: You can answer your own question now or take it down.

Comment: You may also wanna see [find_overlapping](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.find_overlapping-method).